# Arrows keys in R

Tags: r

In R, I do press the arrow keys, and 2 things happen :

On one hand, the symbols ^[[A^[[A^[[A appear;

On the other hand, shall I start typing a command, such as "library", I begin by typing the first 2 letters "li", click  "left arrow", and the result is "li   "(i.e. lots of spaces) instead of having the command "library" written on the screen.

Is there any way to fix it please ?

Comment: Are you in the RGui or in RStudio?

Comment: on R command line .

Comment: on R command line . After I start R, I do type  : library("ggplot2"), and "enter". On the next line, I click "up arrow key", or other arrow keys, and the symbols :  ^[[A^[[A^[[C show on the screen

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue. When I have installed R, I did set "with-readline=no"? I should have set "with-readline=yes".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly solve the problem, but for anyone else who arrives here, the vast majority of the time when using R, you may find the RStudio IDE a very nice environment for R coding, and of course the up arrow will not produce the ^[[A^[[A^[[A but simply go to the previous line of code if in the script pane, or the previously executed line of code if in the console.

TL;DR download and install RStudio (unless you know you really want to code in the R terminal or Rgui, which is okay for some purposes).